# Jmeter test status on non-gui mode

Tags: jmeter, kubernetes-helm

How can i get jmeter test status in non-gui mode.
Jenkins install jmeter helm chart on kuberntes and start the test as part of the installation, meaning that after the chart installed a script entry point will run automatically inside the container, jenkins is only trigger the chart. i want to know when the test is finished and get back the status to jenkins from the pod to publish the report test result on jenkins.

Comment: When you say "start the test as part of the installation", how does the trigger to the test actually happen? Is it through command line or is there a separate Jenkins job for this? Please do elaborate the entire scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When [JMeter's non-gui test execution](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) is finished it returns a normal [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) which can be obtained:

1. [`%errorlevel%`](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) environment variable in Windows
2. [`$?`](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) environment variable in Unix and derivatives

Not knowing the details of how you launch JMeter it is quite hard to come up with exact Jenkins configuration but I'm pretty much sure that you can utilize the aforementioned variables to get the JMeter execution status

Answer (score 0):

if you are triggering jmeter scripts via jenkins , you can have a post build operation after script execution using jenkins.

I am using powershell in jenkins to run jmeter in non gui mode, once test is done doing other post build operations.

Comment: I'm not triggering jmeter script via jenkins. I am using jenkins only to install distributed jmeter helm chart. As part of the helm installation after the container is up, the test.jmx script is running, i want to know when the test is finished in the container, i need a return status or something like that.